# Electron Error: Requires constructor call

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

While trying the electron using their [Quick Start here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start/). I encountered a weird problem. Searching on google yields no results.

following is my directory tree

.
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── node_modules
│   └── electron-prebuilt
└── package.json

contents of `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "desktop-widget",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^0.4.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

contents of `main.js`

```
'use strict';

const electron      = require('electron');
const app           = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://', __dirname, 'index.html');

    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
    })

});
```

on running the command `node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron .`
i get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was real silly of me

I missed the `new` keyword.
plus my loadURL function call is wrong (though i encountered it later and had nothing to do with the above error). In all, this final thing worked for me:

`main.js`

```
'use strict';

const electron      = require('electron');
const app           = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
    })

});
```

Comment: Electron has no problem with es6 you can simplify your imports with `const  {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');`